# How to create multimap from List of triple tuples in Scala?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a list of tuple3 List[(A, B, C)]. What is the best way to convert it to a multimap, which maps Map[A, Map[B, List[C]]]?

I know how to do it with Tuple2 but how to do it with Tuple3

Comment: no, it isn't, I am trying to make json from joined tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My only suggestion is to use `.mapValues(_.` instead of `.map(x => x._1 -> x._2.`:

```
list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._3)))
```

Comment: That depends. 'mapValues` produces a view, not an actual map, so there can be arguments either way.

Comment: But an upvote for the symmetry and the single use of _1, _2, _3 in order :)

Answer (score 3):

Not shorter, but possibly clearer:

Some test data:

```
val x = List(('a', 1, 2.0), ('a', 2, 3.0), ('a', 1, 6.0), ('b', 3, 4.0), ('c', 4, 5.0))
```

Define a function to make a map from tuples, making lists of values for each key:

```
def makeMergedMap[A,B](xs:List[(A, B)]) = xs.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

Remap the input tuples to make pairs

```
val y=x.map(e=>(e._1, (e._2, e._3)))
//  List((a,(1,2.0)), (a,(2,3.0)), (a,(1,6.0)), (b,(3,4.0)), (c,(4,5.0)))
```

Now merge-map the outer tuples, then merge-map each value in the result.

```
makeMergedMap(y).mapValues(makeMergedMap(_)) 

// Map(b -> Map(3 -> List(4.0)),
//     a -> Map(2 -> List(3.0), 1 -> List(2.0, 6.0)),
//     c -> Map(4 -> List(5.0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i managed to do it with

```
list.groupBy(_._1).map(x => x._1 -> x._2.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._3)))
```

if you have shorter answer, you're welcome